# Is it possible to generate a private key with one file in de- and encrypted version?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key, pgp

Is it possible to generate a private key out of a decrypted file and a encrypted file. For example, if I have an encrypted image and I have the original one, can I generate the private key out of them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about encryption, not programming. Might be a good fit for http://security.stackexchange.com, but I'm sure it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with RSA. It's called a known plain text attack.

It's important to use proper (OAEP) padding with RSA, or an [attacker might be able to trick you into decrypting a message.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_chosen-ciphertext_attack#Practical_attacks) But, this takes millions of attempts, and it only decrypts one message, it doesn't recover the key.